# Can someone decrypt this javascript ..?

Tags: javascript, decode

I found this code in extension. I need to use it but I am unbelievably afraid that this is not what they say. I'm afraid that this is a malicious script?

Here is the code in pastebin :

```
var _0xfc98=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x2E\x63\x75\x61\x68\x64\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x30\x30\x31\x2E\x70\x68\x70",
```

the full code is here ---- > http://pastebin.com/YRquAQiU

Please help :)

Comment: I don't think this is the full thing.

Comment: the full code is here http://pastebin.com/YRquAQiU

Comment: Really? Just do `console.log(_0xfc98)` and you'll see it

Comment: `https://fb.cuahd.com/001.php`

Comment: the full code is here pastebin.com/YRquAQiU –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this script and see for yourself:

```js
var _0xfc98=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x2E\x63\x75\x61\x68\x64\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x30\x30\x31\x2E\x70\x68\x70"];
console.log(_0xfc98);
```